# スマホで息が吹きかけられたことを検知するには？

Tags: ios, android

[ブロークン画面 Prank](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crack.screen.prank.bfun&hl=ja)という android アプリ（ios版もあり）は画面が割れたようにみせかける機能をもったいたずらアプリなんですが
このアプリには「息をふきかけると画面上に炎が燃えるエフェクトが現れる」といく機能があります

**アプリ起動画面**
[image: アプリ起動画面]

**息を吹きかけることを促す表示**
[image: 息を吹きかけることを促す表示]

**息を吹きかけると炎のエフェクトが出る**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

andoroid や ios のセンサーには風を感知するセンサーはなかったようなんですが（[iOSで使えるセンサー・ハードウェア機能](http://qiita.com/takitakit/items/c84fdac046ef8b0c0b3a)）
どのようにして息が吹き込まれたことを検知しているんでしょうか？

Comment: 動画があることや自己回答があることを質問側に記載するメリットはなにかあるのでしょうか…？

Comment: @unarist 動画あり、などをタイトルに含めることは個人的にブログやトピックのタイトルを決めるときに習慣的にやってきたことなので、もし問題があると思われたなら削除してもらってもかまいません

自己回答ありと記載しているのは……うーんこれもよくわかっていないんですが、自己回答があることを前提の質問は自作自演をしているように個人的に感じてしまうためあらかじめ閲覧者に知らせることにしていたんです。

どちらもかなり主観的なで個人的なルールですので、もしスタフロにそぐわないようであれば削除します。モデレーター権限で削除してもらってもかまいません。

正直、自分でも習慣的にやっているこの行為がスタフロに適しているか判断がつかないため、メタで質問を建てようかと思っていました

Comment: @unarist さんの意見を個人では判断しかねたのでメタな質問をしてみました。コメントで話が広がり過ぎるといけないので、意見がある場合はこちらのほうでおねがいします http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2132/5505

Answer (score 9):

[自己回答です]

[How to detect blow in android device microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248784/how-to-detect-blow-in-android-device-microphone)（アンドロイドデバイスのマイクで息を吹きかけたことを検知するには？）

の質問の回答には以下のようにあります。

> The job of detecting when a user blows into the microphone is
>   separable into two parts: (1) taking input from the microphone and (2)
>   listening for a blowing sound. The noise/sound of someone blowing into
>   the mic is made up of low-frequency sounds. We’ll use a low pass
>   filter to reduce the high frequency sounds coming in on the mic; when
>   the level of the filtered signal spikes we’ll know someone’s blowing
>   into the mic.
>
> Source:
>   http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/
>
> EDIT And here is some small SoundMeter class for Android:
>   http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/SoundMeter.java?r=2

つまり、息や風を感知するセンサーが端末に搭載されているわけではなく
マイクのノイズを検知して息が吹きかけられた音を聞いて炎のエフェクトを出しているんです

Youtubeで動画撮りました
https://youtu.be/FDg-BKu9CIE

PCでYoutubeを開いて「風の音」という動画を再生し
アンドロイドのマイクに風の音を聞かせています
結果： 炎のエフェクトがでました

Comment: 動画のリンクがみれなかったので youtube に動画を公開しなおしました